# Python prime list

Tags: python

```
integer = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
if integer >= 2:
    print(2)
for i in range(2, integer + 1): # range 2,3,...,integer (excludes 1)
    for j in range(2, i): # we are going to try dividing by these
        if i % j == 0: # not prime
            break
        else: # is prime
            print(i)
```

input:

```
7
```

output:

```
2
3
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
```

output I want:

```
2
3
5
7
```

## adding more detail to get past error:

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 5):

You're printing `i` for every value of `j` that doesn't divide it, until you get a value that does divide it and you execute `break`.

You should only print `i` when you don't break out of the loop. Put the `else:` statement on the `for` loop, not `if`. This `else:` statement is executed when the loop finishes normally instead of breaking.

```
for i in range(2, integer + 1): # range 2,3,...,integer (excludes 1)
    for j in range(2, i): # we are going to try dividing by these
        if i % j == 0: # not prime
            break
    else: # is prime
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `print(i)` in the outer for loop with a flag that keeps track of the result.

```py
for i in range(2, integer + 1): # range 2,3,...,integer (excludes 1)
    isPrime = True
    for j in range(2, i): # we are going to try dividing by these
        if i % j == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
    if isPrime:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is slightly wrong. I have added the correct code below with comments :

```
integer = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

if integer >= 2:
    print(2)

for i in range(2, integer + 1): # range 2,3,...,integer (excludes 1)
    prime=true                       #assume that i is prime
    for j in range(2, i):       # we are going to try dividing by these
        if i % j == 0:          # not prime
            prime=false             # we now know it is not prime
            break
    if prime==true:                # if we didn't do prime=0, then it's a prime
        print(i)
```

What you were doing is printing `i` for every `j` from `2 to i` that did not divide `i`. But instead, what had to be done is print `i` only once when none of the j from `2 to i` divided `i`.

Hope you understand the mistake and this clears your doubt !